# Specific user "spamming" questions of the same type

Tags: discussion, specific-user, low-quality-posts

I noticed a user has posed many questions, none of them answered and all of them of the same type. They have not responded comments nor improved the questions in any way.

How am I as a community member supposed to react to this? The questions basically take away front-page space for much more interesting questions and do not provide enough generality to be of future use.

Answer (score 9):

How to react? Downvote the questions, if you haven't already. At $-4$, questions are removed from the front page.

And vote to close if you think they should be closed. (I happen to think so.)

<sup>I downvoted two of those questions and voted to close one of them; now I am out of downvotes and closevotes.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the info on the $-4$, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a supplement to [an answer by another user whose display name frequently changes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16979/8348), but there are automatic systems in place for when a specific user posts too many "poor quality" questions.

- When too many questions by a particular user have been closed/put on-hold, an automatic flag is raised for the moderators, who may (and usually do) contact the user about their low-quality questions, pointing out guidelines for improving their questions. A prolonged habit of posting low-quality questions may be a reason for a temporary suspension (though admittedly this is pretty rare, probably largely because of the next bullet point).
- When the cumulative "quality" of a user's questions passes below some fairly low bar, the user will be [temporarily blocked from asking questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/2361699), and this can escalate to a [more permanent question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/214632).

Comment: Is the temporary block (your first link in second bullet) active anywhere except SO? The announcement says it's being tested only there. Other SE sites have [quality ban warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236800/).